# maintain formatting entered into an html form?

Tags: php, forms, email, formatting

Im setting up a web form, and I'm trying to have it where visitors can paste their resumes into a text area. Then I want to email the info using php mail(). 
But the resume info is just stored in the variable as one long string with no formatting.

Is there a way I can send the pasted resume text to the client in the resume format? Maintaining all the line breaks and stuff?

He wants to avoid having people upload resumes.

Comment: Are "people" really that uncomfortable with uploading resumes? You have to have them in an e-mailable format of some sort for every other company already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A tinymce-like editor would be good stuff. 
The simplest and fastest, though, would be to use things like http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php to keep the line breaks. It should do regarding that.

Comment: thanks so much Alfabravo! Thats even easier for now. The CKEditor is gonna be great for later, but for now the php nl2br() works best.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to look at some plugin like [CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com/) or [TinyMCE](http://www.tinymce.com/). What you will get back will be an HTML representation of what got pasted in. Be warned, though, that this will not be an exact representation (and probably can't be!).

Answer (score 0):

Another way would be to have them save it in a portable format like the new MS XML, or the old RTF.  Then you can keep the formatting and use xslt or some other parser(or translator) to build your own version of the resume.